# Drawing sharp circle bitmap - android canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing, android-canvas, geometry

What can I do apart from using

```
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

in order to get a sharp edges of the circular bitmap? I can see the edges being not as sharp as I'd like them to be

Comment: show the result of the image...

Comment: edges? which edges? is it a circle or what? by definition, a circle has no edges.